# ios push notification connection refused

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have a AWS server which runs centos 7 operating system. The server has CSF installed and is a production server. My site is running fine on it (PHP). Now when I am trying to send a notification to ios I am getting connection refused error. Then when I did telnet I got the following response: 
**telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195**
Trying 17.188.166.22...
telnet: connect to address 17.188.166.22: Connection refused
Trying 17.188.166.23...
telnet: connect to address 17.188.166.23: Connection refused ...

 In outgoing ports aws server security allows all traffic.
Why is this happening ? Do I need to open inbound ports for 2195? I read in this site that its not required.

Comment: telnet using localhost and see your certificates/configurations are correct

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: using your terminal or command line

Comment: Issue solved. I had to open port in CSF.

Comment: nice to hear that